# Turn off WSL Ubuntu echo when typing commands

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu 18.04, when I type a command like `echo hi`, I see the following in my window:

```
user@DESKTOP-WHATEVER:~$ echo hi
echo hi
hi
```

When I would like it to look like this:

```
user@DESKTOP-WHATEVER:~$ echo hi
hi
```

This may not seem like a huge issue but I believe there is some type of annoying verbose setting that is turned on because if I try to use the autocomplete tab key when change directories (example command of `cd /bin` where I hit tab after the `i` in bin, I get:

```
user@DESKTOP-WHATEVER:~$ cd /biwords=("${@:3:2}")
cword="$3"
cur="$3"
cur="$3"
cword="$3"
prev="$3"
words=("${@:3:2}")
n/
cd /bin/
```

I tried to use `stty -echo` and that kind of worked but then I cannot see what I type until I hit enter and I do not want that either.  Please let me know if there is something I can modify to suppress the echo/turn off the verbose output.  Thanks.

Comment: Does `set +x` help?

Comment: Nope still the same thing.

Comment: I’m not familiar with WSL, do you have a `.bashrc` file? Did you make any changes to it? Do you have any clue what could have caused this, any changes you made or commands you ran? If so please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: Yes I have one at ~/.bashrc but I have not made any changes to it. This is how it came out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dessert was very close with his comment. `set +v` fixed it.